# Using avg(count()) function

Tags: sql, oracle

In a dns log table, trying to use this query to get an avg. number of dns queries within a day:

```
select to_char(log_time, 'DD-MM-YYYY'),log_client,avg(count(*)) as nums from msint
where to_char(log_time, 'DD-MM-YYYY') = '25-09-2013' and log_client = '10.10.10.1';
```

and get an error `"nested group function without GROUP BY"`
but when I add `group by log_client,log_time`, get another error `not a single-group group function`

Maybe someone can help me with a solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below query, check whether the result is expected.

```
select 
  log_time,
  log_client,
  avg(nums) nums
From(
  select 
    to_char(log_time, 'DD-MM-YYYY')log_time,
    log_client,
    count(*) over(partition by to_char(log_time, 'DD-MM-YYYY'), log_client) as nums 
    from msint
  where 
  to_char(log_time, 'DD-MM-YYYY') = '25-09-2013' and 
  log_client = '10.10.10.1' 
)x
group by log_time, log_client;
```

Comment: Thanks. That gives some output, but im still not sure if its right. Just testing.

Comment: I guess taking average on Count(*) doesn't make any sense since grouping is done based on same columns, any way I altered the query without error.

Answer (score 0):

use group by along with having clause.
if possible please share your table structure so that query can be checked against it.

Comment: here is the structure of the table `CREATE TABLE MSINT 
(
  ID NUMBER NOT NULL 
, LOG_CLIENT VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) 
, LOG_QUERY VARCHAR2(512 BYTE) 
, LOG_TIME TIMESTAMP(6) WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE 
, CONSTRAINT MSINT_PK PRIMARY KEY 
  (
    ID 
  )`

Comment: which db you are using? Are you sure your create command has worked?Please provide some data also.

Comment: all i have is this `Name Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ID                                        NOT NULL NUMBER
 LOG_CLIENT                                         VARCHAR2(50)
 LOG_QUERY                                          VARCHAR2(512)
 LOG_TIME                                           TIMESTAMP(6) WITH LOCAL TIME
                                                     ZONE`, and its oracle